# How to make custom directive run function in angularjs 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I make a directive run a function like the other built in directives in angular?

In example:

```
<div ng-repeat="someId in myList" my-directive="runFunctionInScope(someId, divHtmlElement)" />


myApp.directive('myDirective', function ()
{
    return function (scope, element, attrs)
    {
        //??
    }
}
```

Comment: When (in which event) you want to execute your function? What is your exact need, please explain that?

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/C2G3Cg/

Comment: Immanuel: When the object is created, I want to call a function which applies some custom input event listeners to the <div>. I initially tried to use ng-init, but it does not seem to pass the element it self. I upgraded the sample to include the divHtmlElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the below code snippet. Also please check [this plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/UpYTmptxU3jvy8n8?preview) for working example of your given scenario.

**Template:**

```
<div ng-repeat="someId in myList" my-method='theMethodToBeCalled' my-id='someId.id' />
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myList=[{ 
      id: 1,
      value: 'One'
    }, { 
      id: 2,
      value: 'Two'
    }];
  $scope.theMethodToBeCalled = function(id) { 
    alert(id); 
  };
});
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive("myMethod",function($parse) {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: { 
        method:'&myMethod',
        id: '=myId'
      },
      link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
        var expressionHandler = scope.method();
        expressionHandler(scope.id);
      }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```